# I made a python bot that gets the price of a stock but how do I make it so the argument doesn't use a space?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def stockprice(ctx, stock):
    await ctx.send(stock + ' price: ' + getStockPrice(stock))
```

I made a python bot that gets the price of a stock but how do I make it so the argument doesn't  use #a space?

**Example:**

```
!stockprice bitcoin => !stockprice.bitcoin
```

Comment: do you mean stock.strip() to remove white spaces ?

Comment: if you want to recognize command `!stockprice.bitcoin` then you should use `on_message()` to edit message - and when you get message `!stockprice.bitcoin` then convert it to message `!stockprice bitcoin` and send it to `process_commands()`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your problem.

---

If you want to remove spaces/tabs/enters from both sides of string then you need only

```
stock = stock.strip()
```

---

If you want to use command as single string with dot - like `!stockprice.bitcoin` - then you will have to use `on_message(message)` to convert it to `!stockprice bitcoin` and use `process_commands()` to send it to `@client.command()`

More or less something like this

```
@client.event
def on_message(msg):

    if msg.author.bot:
        return

    if msg.content.startswith('!stockprice.'):
       msg.content = msg.content.replace('!stockprice.', '!stockprice ')
    
    await process_commands(msg)
```